# Can a sequence contain an infinite number of numbers 1 or above and still converge to a non 1 value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Can we have a sequence $a_n$ that has an infinite amount of 1's, yet still converge to a number $\neq$ 1?

I know that the sequence of $(-1)^n$ from 1 to $\infty$ does not converge, but can this be remedied if we exclude the negative numbers?

Comment: The answer is NO. A sequence cannot converge to a number and stay away from it by a finite amount infinitely often all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If an infinite sequence has a limit $L$, then any infinite subsequence has the same limit $L$.